# custom marshalling of cassandra column using phantom dsl

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I would like to define a new Column/converter to marshal a case class to a primitive type and back again using phantom dsl.

in slick 3.1.1 I can do this easily:

```
  implicit val idTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Id, Long](
    { (v) ⇒ v.value },
    { (s) ⇒ Id(s) }
  )
```

This allows me to use the `Id` anywhere in a slick query and it will be implicitly converted back and forth.

I have tried to derive my own Columns and conversions in phantom by extending `AbstractColumn` (and other) but with no luck.

How do I do this in phantom dsl.

Answer (score 0):

With apologies for the late reply, you would simply use `Primitive.derive`. More details on the [**official docs**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/docs/basics/primitives.md#deriving-new-primitives-from-existing-ones).

```
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._

case class Test(value: String)

object Test {
  implicit val testPrimitive: Primitive[Test] = {
    Primitive.derive[Test, String](_.value)(Test.apply)
  }
}
```